# Typescript pattern for abstract generic functions seems to be broken

Tags: typescript, generics, abstract

I have a pattern like this that I used A LOT in code I wrote months (even years) ago using older versions of the typescript compiler, maybe 1.8 - 2.2:

```
interface IBase { };

interface IExtends extends IBase {
    key2: string;
};

abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    protected abstract myFunc<T extends IBase>(arg: string): T;
};

class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    protected myFunc(arg: string): IExtends {
        return { key2: arg };
    }
};
```

Back when I wrote this code, Typescript did not complain at all, and handled this as you would expect.

But now, typescript (version 2.8.1) complains:

```
src/errorInvestigation.ts(12,15): error TS2416: Property 'myFunc' in type 'MyClass' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MyAbstractClass'.
  Type '(arg: string) => IExtends' is not assignable to type '<T extends IBase>(arg: string) => T'.
    Type 'IExtends' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

If typescript is correct in marking this as an error, then what would be the correct way to accomplish the same thing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to jcalz for starting me down a research path, leading to a regrettable but workable answer

*I am still baffled as to why typescript made this change, because I see no problem with the original way of describing this.*

The answer is to promote the generics to the class level rather than leaving them on the methods.  This has pros and cons, in my opinion more cons than pros.  The pros are that the body of the abstract class is perhaps cleaner and easier to read.  The cons are that if you have many different types that need to be handled within the same class, that class itself needs to declare all those types on the class declaration and every derived class needs to do that too, which means this is harder to read I think.  But it will do the job.

Here is the complete answer as I see it, and I would love anyone (including jcalz!) to chime in with further thoughts/refinements:

```
interface IArgBase {
    baseArgKey: string;
};

interface IReturnBase {
    baseReturnKey: string;
};

interface IPromiseBase {
    basePromiseKey: string;
};

interface IArgExtends extends IArgBase {
    extendedArgKey: string;
};

interface IReturnExtends extends IReturnBase {
    extendedReturnKey: string;
};

interface IPromiseExtends extends IPromiseBase {
    extendedPromiseKey: string;
};

abstract class MyAbstractClass<TArg extends IArgBase, TReturn extends IReturnBase, TPromise extends IPromiseBase>{
    protected abstract myFunc(arg: TArg): TReturn;
    protected abstract myAsyncFunc(arg: TArg): Promise<TPromise>;
};

class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass<IArgExtends, IReturnExtends, IPromiseExtends> {
    protected myFunc(arg: IArgExtends): IReturnExtends {
        return { baseReturnKey: arg.baseArgKey, extendedReturnKey: arg.extendedArgKey };
    };
    protected myAsyncFunc(arg: IArgExtends): Promise<IPromiseExtends> {
        return Promise.resolve({ basePromiseKey: arg.baseArgKey, extendedPromiseKey: arg.extendedArgKey });
    };
};
```

Comment: > "I see no problem with the original way of describing this."

I explained in my edit... The non-generic override doesn't match the thing it overrides.  The parent returns `T` for any `T extends IBase` specified by the function caller, but the override returns `IExtends`, which has no relation to `T`.

Comment: Your solution is a good one.   If you make the whole parent class generic (instead of just one method) you can specify the generic parameter in subclasses the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably don't really mean for `myFunc` to be generic.  The following signature

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    protected abstract myFunc<T extends IBase>(arg: string): T;
};
```

means that a `MyAbstractClass` has a `myFunc()` method which takes a `string` input and returns any subtype of `IBase` that the *caller* specifies.  But you want it to return a subtype of `IBase` that the *implementer* specifies.  If `myFunc` weren't `protected` you could see the problem quickly like

```
declare const myAbstractInstance: MyAbstractClass;
let iBase = myAbstractInstance.myFunc<IBase>('hey'); // IBase
let iExtends = myAbstractInstance.myFunc<IExtends>('hey'); // IExtends?!
let iOther = myAbstractInstance.myFunc<IBase & {foo: string}>('hey'); // What?!
iOther = iExtends; // error, not assignable
```

Where you call the same function with the same argument three times, and at runtime they would have the same output, but apparently TypeScript thinks the outputs are of different types.  This is a strange pattern and not what you are intending to convey anyway.

And I'm not sure exactly when it got enforced, but you shouldn't be allowed to override a generic function with a non-generic one unless the non-generic one really is a subtype of the generic one.  But since `T` can be *any* subtype of `IBase` specified by the caller, the only non-generic types that are definitely assignable to every possible `T` would be `never` and `any`.  And you don't want to return those, I think.

---

It sounds like you just want `myFunc` to return an `IBase` or some subtype of it specified by the subclass implementation.  If so, then you can do this without generics at all:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
  protected abstract myFunc(arg: string): IBase;
};
```

This will work for you. The subclass

```
class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    protected myFunc(arg: string): IExtends {
        return { key2: arg };
    }
};
```

is compatible with `MyAbstractClass` because method return types are [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), meaning that if `Y` is a subtype of `X`, then a method of `Y` is allowed to return a subtype of the analogous method of `X`.

This would be different if you needed the method *parameter* to be narrower in the subclass, because method parameters are contravariant.  In the case that `T` was the type of `arg` and not the return type, the above shouldn't work... but it *does* happen to work because method parameters are still considered [bivariant](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant). But that is not your use case, I think.  (Update: I see that it *is* your use case.  Method parameters are bivariant for this reason apparently, so try it out.  Personally I don't like bivariance and there are more "correct" workarounds but they are probably more trouble than they are worth.)

Hope that helps; good luck.

Comment: In my little test case, it works fine, thanks.  I need to spread this throughout my code to test if this is complete - likely you get the answer!  Thanks for quick turnaround.

Comment: Grrrrr.  I do need it sometimes for parameters.  And I am using it sometimes in Promises.  So I think that while this is a useful answer, it still isn't complete.  I have found a different fix where I place the generic on the abstract class rather than on the method, and use it that way.  Which works.... but could end up with a scenario (in my use case) where I have to put a LOT of generics on the abstract class, making the code less readable.  So initial question still applies, should Typescript allow my old pattern?

Comment: I think it will end up working in method parameters also, which are currently treated as bivariant.  Try it out.  The old pattern is not great because you don't want the method to be generic.  I can elaborate in an edit.

Comment: Thanks.  I just posted what I think the complete answer is.... you are right that method parameters worked, but type specifiers to promises did not work.  Would love to hear your further thoughts.